# Please see if this sentence is correct

Tags: sentence-construction

Folks,

I found the following sentence in a [news article](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2017/apr/09/brexit-hasnt-happened-yet-changing-all-the-time-conservatives). Please let me know if this sentence is correct.

> Nigel Farage did not accept the people had spoken in 1975.

I think that 'what' should be placed between 'accept' and 'the', but I'm not sure. Please let me know.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, there must be a "what" between "accept" and "the", As the sentence makes no sence without it.

Comment: Putting 'what' between 'accept' and 'the' would mean 'spoken' should be changed to 'said' I'd say it's better to put 'that' between 'accept' and 'the' instead. 'Nigel Farage did not accept 'that' the people had spoken in 1975'

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't necessarily need another word, and adding *what* would change the meaning.  As is it now, it could mean "Farage did not accept *the fact that* the people had spoken.” Adding *what* would make it mean "Farage did not accept *the things that* the people said." It isn't very clearly written, though, and if the author had added another word the meaning would be clearer.

Comment: I think we'll need a preposition if we add *what*. "What people had spoken of".